# Path integral on $\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,-1]$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Let $\gamma$ a path such that $\gamma(0) = -i$ and  $\gamma(1) = i$. Moreover, $\gamma(t) \in \mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,-1] \ \forall t \in [0,1]$.

How can I compute $\displaystyle\int_\gamma \! \frac{1}{z+1} \, \mathrm{d}z$?

I rewrite $$\int_\gamma \! \frac{1}{z+1} \, \mathrm{d}z = \int_0^1 \! \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)+1} \, \mathrm{d}t$$ How can I proceed from here?

Comment: $\displaystyle  z = t\,\mathrm{i}$ with $\displaystyle t \in \left(-1,1\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{\gamma}{\dd z \over z + 1} &
\,\,\,\stackrel{z\ =\ \ic t}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{-1}^{1}{\ic\,\dd t \over \ic t + 1} =
\ic\int_{-1}^{1}{1 - \ic t \over 1 + t^{2}}\,\dd t =
2\ic\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over 1 + t^{2}} = 2\ic\,{\pi \over 4} =
\bbx{{\pi \over 2}\,\ic}
\end{align}